# Meta tags to set IE10 to Browser Mode IE9 and Document Mode IE5 Quirks

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, meta-tags

I'm updating an old enterprise website. Which doesn't render properly

If you have IE10 then the site isn't rendered properly unless you have Browser Mode set to IE9 and Document Mode set to IE5 Quirks.

With Meta tags how can you set both of these? I can manage to set one or the other but not both.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Have you tried playing with different DOCTYPEs?

Comment: You cannot set browser mode except with browser settings. OTOH, browser mode only affects the identification that the browser sends to a server. You have probably misanalyzed the problem. In any case, there is not sufficient information – no description of what the actual rendering problem is.